# get minimum cost to produce unavailable chemical algorithm

Tags: algorithm, equation, minimum

Lets say I need a chemical which consists 2 substances with ratio of Rx:Ry where GCD(Rx,Ry) = 1, but unfortunately I dont find it in medical shops,

We have different medicines which consists these substances

AiX + BiY = Ci where Ai is ratio of substance X, Bi is ratio of substance Y and Ci is cost

We have list of few medicines

A0X + B0Y = C0;
A1X + B1Y = C1;
.
.
.
AnX + BnY = Cn;

I can use any item only once and if I use it, I will use whole.
Now I want to know which all medicines should I use to get the required chemical with minimum cost?

Thanks in advance.

I tried something like

[image]

with this I am getting the result, but not the minimum cost,

Can you please suggest me to go in right direction. thanks in advance

Comment: Please post code as text, not an image of handwritten code (I am used to saying this about screenshots of code, but... this is a novelty).

Comment: Could you give some constraints about `n` and `a[i]`, `b[i]`  and `c[i]`.